# Implementing a WebRequest retry

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I have a service that I'm using to download a lot data from the Bungie API to a SQL db. The issue I'm having is that every once in a while, their server responds with a 504 error. I was wondering if anyone had any useful suggestions on how I could get my WebRequest code to retry after a failed response. Here's what I have going on now:

```
    private async Task<T> Deserialize<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            return Deserialize<T>(json);
        }
    }

    private T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }

    private Task<WebRequest> Request(object service, string methodName, object model)
    {
        var requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder();
        requestBuilder.AddHeaders(Headers);
        return requestBuilder.Build(service, methodName, model);
    }

    protected virtual Task<WebResponse> Response(WebRequest request)
    {
        return request.GetResponseAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> Request<T>(object service, string methodName, object model = null)
    {
        var request = await Request(service, methodName, model);
        WebResponse response = await Response(request);
        return await Deserialize<T>(response.GetResponseStream());
    }
```

When an error occurs, the line `WebResponse response = await Response(request);` returns null.

Comment: Have you looked at using Polly? http://www.acodersjourney.com/2016/04/polly-framework-policy-based-retries-transient-errors-c/

Comment: You need to do the retry in Request<T>.  Should not be the hard.

Comment: Request<T> is where I thought of having it, but I'm not sure exactly how to implement it.